# TextBlock wrapping of text in Silverlight XAML file

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, textblock

TextBlock wrapping of text in Silverlight XAML file.

I have a wierd and annoying problem.  I have a textblock that is inside a stackpanel that is Oriented horizontal.  It would be nice if I could have the textblock appear in multiple lines nicely wrapped.  How could I do that?

Comment: set the maxium width of the TextBlock?

Comment: What is the Stackpanel inside of? Is a scrollviewer in the ancestory of the the StackPanel?

Answer (score 5):

to wrap text, you set the property TextWrapping to Wrap:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

[MSDN doc is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: That'll work assuming the containing panel limits the available width.  Thats a big assumption.

Answer (score 4):

By default StackPanels do not limit the size of their contents in the direction of Orientation. That is the direction they keep on growing.

You mention you have it Orientation = Horizontal, so that will not constrain the width of a TextBox within it.

If you want text wrapping: you either need to use a grid for the container (which will constrain it's children) or set a fixed width on the TextBox.